# Android: How to make a drawable with a multicolor gradient?

Tags: android, android-drawable, linear-gradients, android-shape

I made this:

```
  ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory shaderFactory = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                    new int[]{
                            0xF44336,
                            0xFFB74D,
                            0xFFE082,
                            0xAED581,
                            0x4CAF50,
                            0xAED581,
                            0xFFE082,
                            0xFFB74D,
                            0xF44336},
                    new float[]{
                            0, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.375f, 0.5f, 0.625f, 0.75f, 0.875f, 1.0f},
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            return linearGradient;
        }
    };
    PaintDrawable paint = new PaintDrawable();
    paint.setShape(new RectShape());
    paint.setShaderFactory(shaderFactory);
```

But I can't see anything when I set it as background in a view.

Comment: use `ShapeDrawable` not `PaintDrawable`

Comment: it's still transparent

Comment: what are you doing with `paint` leter on?

Comment: I simply call setBackground(paint), I tried with buttons, imageview and textview but no effects

Comment: use 0xffxxxxxx in color definitions

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! with 0xFF (not 0xff) the colors appeared. Another doubt, do you know how to programmatically set the angle of the gradient to make it horizontal?

Comment: no difference if `0xFF` or `0xff`, for horizontal gradient see the first 4 params of `LinearGradient` constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting this drawable to your view background

```
GradientDrawable rainbow = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED});
```

Comment: I have more than 3 colors

Comment: Thanks for accepting it correct, I also used it in progress bar indeterminateDrawable,, some more modification will make it rainbow color moving as loader, like gmail loading bar below title bar,,,