# How do I make a gradient background for my seekbar?

Tags: android, seekbar

**Not a duplication question, so please read first.**

I am trying to make my seekbar look like this[image: Seekbar image] . The problem is, there is no such library on github or any code for that for android. How do I do that? This is the closest solution but it supports only 3 colors:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<!-- background -->
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="0dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#FF5A00"
            android:centerY="0"
            android:endColor="#FF5A00"
            android:startColor="#FF5A00" />
```

Comment: I would guess that the `startColor` `centerColor` and `endColor` defines what major colors to fade between, try change them so that they are not the same colour (FF5A00 is hex for a color code, where FF is full Red, 5A is about 50% of green and 00 is no blue).

Comment: I have tried it already, I need more colors

Comment: Yes, just try to change the color codes. Each part of the color code is a value between 0 and 255 (hexadecimal: 0-FF). The order is RedGreenBlue. I.E., FF0000 is full red, 00FF00 full green, 0000FF full blue.
Play around with it and see if you find a gradient you like.

Comment: "More colors"? Are you looking for the entire visible color spectrum (or a close approx. thereof) or just how many colors?

Comment: @Barns closest  approx

Comment: @Barns is it possible sir :D

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer to this question. [How to make a drawable with a multicolor gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990598/android-how-to-make-a-drawable-with-a-multicolor-gradient)

Comment: Does anyone find any answer? I am facing a similar issue but got a whole background gradient. I want only played color gradient